# Disable interactions with webview's content

Tags: android, android-webview, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm developing a simple app using Nativescript.

What I would like to achieve is to disable every kind of interaction with a webview component (input focus, push buttons).

I tried:

`<WebView src="mysite.com" isUserInteractionEnabled="false" />`

but I'm still able to tap on buttons within the webview.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You will have to overwrite touch events natively Or simply place a transparent overlay above WebView that will prevent user interactions.